# error when using rake db:migrate command

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am doing a simple rails tutorial intro app and when I type rake db:migrate I get the error

```
Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter
```

but when I try typing

```
sudo gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter
```

I get the error message:

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-sqlite3-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository
>   ERROR:  Possible alternatives: activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter, activerecord-sqlserver-     adapter, activerecord-spatialite-adapter, activerecord-nulldb-adapter, activerecord-dbslayer-    adapter

I tried installing the activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter and it installed ok but I still got the error when trying to migrate the database. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating your sqlite3 gem?

```
$ bundle update sqlite3
```

Other people has solved similar problems just renaming the sqlite3 1.3.X to sqlite3 1.3.4 or higher

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're not using bundler?

Have you tried?

```
sudo gem install sqlite3 -v 1.3.5
```